# Как вывести элементы одномерного массива по возрастанию в С ++

Tags: c++

Как вывести элементы одномерного массива по возрастанию в С ++

Comment: сначала сортировать массив?

Comment: 1) Отсортировать. 2) Вывести. С каким пунктом возникли трудности?

Comment: Как уже было сказано, сначала сортируете удобным для вас методом (особо разницы при небольших массивах не будет), далее выводите. Думаю, такой вопрос не подходит для данного форума

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

/* Пузырьковая сортировка. */
template<typename T>
void Bubble(T* items, std::size_t size)
{
    register std::size_t a, b;
    register std::size_t t;

    for(a = 1; a < size; ++a)
    {
        for(b = size - 1; b >= a; --b)
        {
            if(items[b - 1] > items[b] )
            {
                t = items[b - 1];
                items[b - 1] = items[b];
                items[b] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Show(T* items, std::size_t size)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << items[i] << ' ';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int a[] {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    std::size_t size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);

    Show(a, size);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Bubble(a, size);

    Show(a, size);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Как в параолимпиаде по программированию :D*. `sort(a, a + <a size>);`

Comment: ты участвовал? победил хоть?